# SQL server: calculate age when you have only access to month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a large data file, 58,000,000 records, which contains a field called Birth_Month, with the month and year of people's birth. It is stored as  yyyy-mm, as a string. I need to calculate the age as of 2018-APR-01 (in any date format).

The only way I know about going about this, is to concatenate the Birth_Month  with 01 so it becomes yyyy-mm-dd, and then convert it to a date field. Then follow the usual method of calculating age.

However, as the file is so big, and network I use very busy, I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

EDIT I tried the methodology I mentioned above on a test data set - it did not work!:

```
update #TEST2
set [dob] = #TEST2.Birth_Month + '-01
Select Birth_Month,

DATEDIFF(yyyy,01-04-2018,dob)
    from
    #TEST2
```

Comment: Your method is fine.

Comment: By *large data file* do you mean a local file or is that data stored in your sql server ?

Comment: its on the server, but there is a lot of traffic

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean?

Comment: In the sample data this is what I got: for DOB: 01/02/2013 date  to: 01/04/2018 the answer was 119 not 5

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select cast(replace('2019-01'+'01', '-', '.') as numeric(8,4)) - cast(replace('2017-11'+'01', '-', '.') as numeric(8,4))
```